# how to check time taken by application to submit data in database in .net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to check/find time taken by application to submit data in database when user click on submit button. I want to check my various code to insert data into database & find the fastest code of mine.
So please help me.

Comment: The `SQL Server profiler` can be of great use for this issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use SQL Server Profiler for this task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to calculate the time taken to save data.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

 //Code to save data 

 stopWatch.Stop();

 TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft SQL Server Profiler** can help to SQL Trace for monitoring an instance of the Database Engine or Analysis Services.

You can capture and save data about each event to a file or table to analyze later. For example, you can monitor a production environment to see which stored procedures are affecting performance by executing too slowly.

For more details about how to use it, check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step) or this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ8Dyv4Uk6E).

Comment: Thank You very Much for your reply. this help me lot. but I want Check that does my 2 tier application is much faster or 3 tier application? How can I do this?